# Writing errors to a text file in a Web Service

Tags: c#, file, soap, queue, file-writing

I have a web service that has a default ErrorLog method for adding Logs to a Db Table. If there's an exception is caught on the ErrorLog Add or the Stored Procedure returns that it failed to add. I'd like to write the error to a textfile on the server, (in theory this should never happen).

Now before actually implementing this, I realize there's a good chance that multiple people could get an error, all of them fail, and all of them try to write to the same text file.

How can I implement a queue on the service, so that the messages get added to the queue and another service / job loops through this queue and adds the errors to the file?

I have tried looking for examples, most of them are very basic. The only thing I really want to know is how I should keep track of the queue? Do I simply create a static class?

Would the below work?

```
public class ErrorLogging
{

    public ErrorLogging(Error error)
    {
        if (ErrorLoggingQueue._GlobalQueue == null)
        {
            ErrorLoggingQueue._GlobalQueue = new Queue<Error>();
        }

        ErrorLoggingQueue._GlobalQueue.Enqueue(error);
    }
}

public static class ErrorLoggingQueue
{
    public static Queue<Error> _GlobalQueue;
}

// Assume that this class/method gets called every x minutes or seconds from  a job or something.
public class JobClass
{
    public void WriteErrors()
    {
        if (ErrorLoggingQueue._GlobalQueue != null)
        {
            while (ErrorLoggingQueue._GlobalQueue.Count != 0)
            {
                Error error = (Error)ErrorLoggingQueue._GlobalQueue.Dequeue();

                // Do stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a logging framework like NLog, log4net ... they will take care of all this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, static variable with a Queue will work and would be shared between requests. Just add locking for enqueue and dequeue to make those operation atomic. Something along these lines:

```
class YourWebservice
{
    static Queue<Error> _GlobalQueue = new Queue<Error>();
    static readonly object queueLock = new object();
    static Thread errorLogger;

    public void SomeWebserviceMethod()
    {
        //Some code...
        //.
        //.

        //Here we want to log an error
        EnqueueError(new Error());
    }
    private void EnqueueError(Error err )
    {
        lock(queueLock)
        {
            _GlobalQueue?.Enqueue(err);
            if ( errorLogger==null || !(errorLogger?.IsAlive ?? false) )
            {
                errorLogger = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteErrors));
                errorLogger?.Start();
            }
        }
    }

    private static Error DequeueError()
    {
        try
        {
            lock (queueLock)
            {
                return  _GlobalQueue?.Dequeue();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            //if we got here it means queue is empty.
        }

        return null;
    }
    private static void WriteErrors()
    {
       Error error = DequeueError();
       while (error!=null)
       {
            //Log error here
            //...
            //..

            error = DequeueError();               
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, there was an error in your code. I went ahead and edited the fix into it. For anyone else looking at this question.

Comment: Weird, I edited your answer to include the fix. Anyway if you started up the application and called the ErrorLogging the first time, it was fine. As soon as the call finished and we were now waiting, and we called it again. It crashed on errorLogger?.Start(); Saying that it was either still running or terminated, and that you can't start either. So I added that to a Try/Catch so that if it fails we re-initialize the ErrorLogger? variable and start it below.

Comment: @xFrenzy47x Thanks for the response. Oh... I c.That's right terminated thread cannot be reused. Mea culpa.  Glad you found solution for that rather quickly. I should have reinitialize the thread if it's no longer running. Devil lives in details and we found one!:)